# Streamingplatform with Unity, Nodejs and Nextjs

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, next.js, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I want to create a streamingplatform in Nextjs on which I can view my unity games (VR) that are being livestreamed. I have set up a websocketserver in nodejs on which I can connect from unity, as well as from nextjs. I'm able to send messages between the two. Now i want to be able to send my camera input from Unity to my frontend in nextjs. How should I do this? I tried doing it with the Unity render streaming package, but this didn't really work out for me. Does anyone have any other recommendations, or should i keep trying with the render streaming package? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.